# Any complete linear subspace is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Suppose a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{H}$ a subspace. Now,  $\mathcal{S}$ can be closed or open in the norm topology depending on whether or not every convergent sequence of elements of $\mathcal{S}$ has a limit in $\mathcal{S}$. If $\mathcal{S}$ is closed, then it is also a complete space, as every convergent sequence is also Cauchy convergent. Suppose then that $\mathcal{S}$ is complete, it is then necessarily closed?

Any counterexample?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Answer (score 1):

Given a sequence $(x_{n})\subseteq S$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $H$, then $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy in $S$. As $S$ is complete, then $x_{n}\rightarrow y$ in $S$, that is, for some $y\in S$. So $x_{n}\rightarrow y$ in $H$. As $H$ is Hausdorff, then $x=y$, so $S$ is closed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then a subspace is complete if and only if it is closed?

Comment: As long as in the normed space, it is true then.

Comment: @user284331 I think you mean in a *complete* normed space.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the missing word.

Comment: More generally, if $X$ is any metric space and $S$ is a subset of $S$ which is complete, then $S$ is closed in $X$.  The converse is true if $X$ is itself complete.  The vector space and norm structure don't play any role here.